# Python Pillow text vertical align

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to position 1 symbol in the top left corner of the given bounding box.

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype('LiberationSans-Regular.ttf', 150)
draw.text((x0, y0), "€", "green", font=font)
```

But when I place text, for example at (0, 0) of the box, it appears with some padding at the top. Also it seems padding size depends on font size.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to calculate size of this padding? And maybe move it on  that exact amount of pixels upwards. 
Basically top pixel of the given symbol must be at y0 of the bounding box, regardless of font and font size.